# Assigning value to a constant dynamically-sized array in the constructor of a class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, constants

- I have two classes, A and B
- Class B has a private member variable which is a constant dynamically
  sized array of object A
- One of the constructors for class B will take a constant reference to
  a Class A object which will be used to set the array in class B

class B:

```
class B
{
  private:
    const A** theArray;
  public:
    B(const A&);
};

B::B(const A& newA)
  : theArray(newA) //<-- ??
{
}
```

When I try to compile the program, I get an error saying "cannot convert from 'const A' to 'const A **' "

How would I pass an object into the member initializer list so I could make an array out of them?

edit 1:
This is for a comsci class assignment. We're learning about classes right now and the assignment has us creating three separate constructors for this particular class (a copy constructor; one to add a new A object into 'theArray' in class B; and a constructor that add the first A object into 'theArray'(this is the constructor in question).)

The idea is that you call the third constructor in the list to create an object. Then if you want to add another A object to the array you would call the second constructor. Then if you wanted a copy of the object you would use the copy constructor.

Comment: You want to set reference of an single object to an array? You cannot make an array out of a single object. You need to pass an pointer to array if you want that not an reference to object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try to compile the program I get an error saying "cannot convert from 'const A' to 'const A **' "

Then, the first thing you must do is understand the compiler error. What is trying to say the compiler?

In the `B` constructor you're initializing a member of the type `const A **` with a given parameter of the type `const A &`; they aren't of the same type and this is why the compiler is complaining.

So, what to do to fix it?

You must make the `B` constructor to take the same type of the member variable as argument.

```
class B
{
private:
    const A** theArray;
public:
    B(const A**);
};

B::B(const A** newA)
    : theArray(newA) //<-- They're of the same type: no problem.
{
}
```

But you must ensure that the calls outside the class matches the constructor definition.

But instead of it, I advise to revise the design, you're sure that naked pointers is the only solution to your problem? You must answer this questions in order to improve the `class B`:

- Where the dynamic memory is created an where is destroyed?
- The `class B` takes the ownership of the given `A**`?

If the `class B` will be the owner of the dynamic memory, you must think about creating and destroying the `theArray` inside the `class B` itself not outside.

If the `class B` will not be the owner of the dynamic memory, you must be very careful about the memory: The memory pointed by `theArray` will be destroyed after of before the `class B`? in other words, could be a `class B` instance with memory pointed by `theArray` already deleted? In this case, smart pointers could be a good help.

Answer (score 1):

That is *not* the way you specify a dynamically sized array in C++.
Your class B should be:

```
class B
{
    std::vector<A> const theArray;
public:
    B( A const& initialA )
        : theArray( n, initialA )
    {
    }
};
```

This leaves open the question of where the `n` (the number of elements
in the array) comes from, and why on earth you would want to create an
immutable array with all elements the same.

In fact, I rather doubt that you accurately describe what you are trying
to do.  Do you in fact want an array of pointers to `A` (with the actual
`A` objects being located elsewhere, and not being part of the `B`
object)?  And with the `A` objects `const` (but not the array—"a
constant dynamically sized array" is an oxymoron).  In that case:

```
class B
{
    std::vector<A const*> theArray;
public:
    B( A const& initialEntry )
        : theArray( 1, &initialEntry )
    {
    }
};
```

You can then add other entries later (always of type `A const*`).

Comment: this is for a comsci class assignment.  We're learning about classes right now and the assignment has us creating three separate constructors for this particular class(a copy constructor; one to add a new A object into 'theArray' in class B; and a constructor that add the first A object into 'theArray'(this is the constructor in question).  The idea is that you call the third constructor in the list to create an object.  Then if you want to add another A object to the array you would call the second constructor.  Then if you wanted a copy of the object you would use the copy constructor

Comment: @LoganBesecker In which case, my first solution is probably what is wanted (with `n == 1`).  This supposes that `A` supports copy, of course.  On the other hand, the goal of the exercise might be to teach you how to program when the rule of three applies, in which case some dynamic allocation would be in order.  In that case, the type of `theArray` should be `A const*`, initialized with `new A[1]`, and with the initial value then assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating any memory for the array of pointers.

And to the constructor you should be passing a pointer of A and not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Of course `std::vector<int>` is preferable - see other answers for how to use it.
**If you really want to use dynamic array - remember to add destructor and copy/move stuff.**

And remember that you need to know what is the A object passed to `B(const A&)`. It cannot be temporary. this newA has to last as long as the B object. If it is dynamic (created by new) - you must know what object will be responsible for deleting it. It is class B or what?

Anyways, just for purpose to show the direct answer:

In C++11 it is quite simple with new `{}` initializer syntax, same as for `std::vector`

```
class B
{
  private:
    const A** theArray;
  public:
    B(const A&);
};

B::B(const A& newA)
  : theArray(new const A*[some_size] { &newA } ) //<-- ??
{}
```

In C++03 an extra static method is needed for creating/initializing dynamic array:

```
class B
{
  private:
    const A** theArray;
    static const A** makeArray(const A& a)
    {
       const A** rv = new const A*[some_size]();
       rv[0] = a;
       return rv;
    }
  public:
    B(const A&);
};

B::B(const A& newA)
  : theArray(makeArray(newA))  //<-- ??
{}
```